# typedef struct format in another typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

How can I declare a `typedef struct` in other `typedef struct`?

```
typedef struct {
    char* type;
    char* destination;
    float price;
    typedef struct {
        int date;
        int month;
        int year;
    }date;
}Offer;
```

I tried something like this but I don't know if its correctly. I want to declare in typedef struct another typedef struct for date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of what you wrote, let's try something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
} OfferDate;


typedef struct {
char* type;
char* destination;
float price;
OfferDate date; 
} Offer;
```

Comment: And, how can I implement date in this function: `Offer create(char* type, char* destination, float price, DATE);` ?

Comment: `Offer create(char* type, char* destination, float price, OfferDate date);` @CristianTimar like this.

Comment: I readed a part from c book, but I needed this instruction urgently . Thanks  !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
typedef struct {
  char* type;
  char* destination;
  float price;
  struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
  } date;
} Offer;
```

This defines `date` as being of an anonymous struct. If you need to have this struct available elsewhere use [*Shark*'s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751199/694576).

Comment: was just about to add that to my answer as an alternative. :)

Comment: @CristianTimar: `Offer create(char* type, char* destination, float price, int day, int month, int year);`?

Comment: He's actually asking how to construct the object, to use that method signature - you require to tell him how to assign the `day`, `month`, and `year` to the struct to be returned. And since it's anonymous, it can't be passed around as a argument. that's the part he's not getting, how to do `Offer.date.day = <myDay>;`

Comment: "*He's actually asking how to construct the object*" well, not in the question. @Shark

Comment: True, he's a bit ambiguous and unclear but I still suspect that's his trouble point. In any case, it doesn't matter much anymore, does it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats incorrect syntax. If you want to define a struct using another struct, you can do it like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a1;
    int a2;
} ExampleStruct1;

typedef struct {
    int b1;
    ExampleStruct1 b2;
} ExampleStruct2;
```